# SQL How can I select data that appear stored in similar columns from two tables ignoring the case?

Tags: sql

For example I have two table A and B which both has a column **people**. And I want to select those people that appears in both table.
However the name in table A is in **Upper** case while those in B only has the first letter in **Upper** case.
For example, there is a BOB in table A and a Bob in table B, and I want Bob to be selected in my result.

Comment: Which RDBMS? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the name to the same case and do an intersect
to find people that appear in both tables

```
select upper(people)
from TableA
intersect
select upper(people)
from TableB
order by 1
```

Comment: thanks I've tried your solution and got what I want!

Comment: sorry I met a new problem.  I want the result to be in alphabetical order. I tried to put the order by query before intersect and at the last but both failed.

Comment: Try `order by 1` just at the end

Answer (score 0):

One method is `join`:

```
select distinct a.name
from tablea a join
     tableb b
     on lower(a.name) = lower(b.name);
```

This is not necessarily efficient, because of the case conversion and `distinct`.  Some databases, by the way, are case-insensitive by default.